# What this syntax in docs mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax

im having trouble understanding something in JS docs syntax.

for example this is taken from ezime docs,  reduce (fn[,init...)

what the "," is for?

thank you!

Comment: Please provide a link the the documentation mentioned in your post.  Additionally, Stack Overflow provides text formatting options using Markdown or the rich editor which help others read your question.

Comment: The `[...]` means optional, so you can either omit it, then the signature is `(fn)` or you can add it, then the signature is `(fn, init)`. the comma is to seperate parameters